# Magento bundle product not saving after upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, bundle-product

Magento bundle product not saving after upgrade please find the below screenshot

[image]

product wheel keeps on rotating.

thanks

Comment: can you please specify which upgrade ?

Comment: 1934 to 1936 version